# Backtrack in mysql with parent child relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, select, php-7

I have been using parent child relationship as following

```
id | parent_id | 
----------------
30 |   0       |
32 |   30      |
33 |   32      |
34 |   32      |
----------------
```

I want to fetch history of **34** so that it will be of ids **34,32,33(because 32 is parent) and 30(untill parent id = 0)**

I used self join but didn't solve my problem . I am doing this in php with mysql.

**query**

```
SELECT f1.id 
  FROM followup as f1 
  JOIN followup as f2 
    ON f1.id = f2.parent_id 
 WHERE f2.id <= 34
```

can anyone help me ?

Comment: Not sure recursion exists in SQL. I think it would be easier if you gathered all the ID relations and worked them in PHP.

Comment: See any one of a thousand answers to similar questions.

Comment: I didn't find any @Strawberry

Comment: You can check this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7161) I think it could help you

Comment: Please tell us what out put you are getting now and what o/p u want.

Comment: I mentioned above that I want to fetch data of  ids that I listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion in SQL is done using Common Table Expressions (CTE), which is basically dynamic views.

```
WITH RECURSIVE rec (id, parent_id, level) AS (
  SELECT id, parent_id, 0 FROM followup WHERE parent_id=0

  UNION ALL

  SELECT id, parent_id, level+1 FROM followup
  JOIN rec ON followup.parent_id = rec.id
)
SELECT * FROM rec;
```

However this is **NOT YET IMPLEMENTED IN MYSQL**. It's a draft documentation for the upcoming MySQL 8.0.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

MySQL currently **does not support this**

MySQL does not support recursion, unless you really wanna have a go at it with stored functions, which is ugly as hell.

You're better off transforming this structure into a de-normalized form once, and keeping to that structure.

So you need to keep a structure like this:

```
id     ancestor_id    distance
30     0              1
32     0              2
33     0              3
34     0              3
32     30             1
33     30             2
34     30             2
33     32             1
34     32             1
```

This will allow you to do a linear query, but will be heavy on the insert logic, since it will have to insert a record for every ancestor node. But since usually information is inserted less frequent than selected, this will be a faster implementation, and it will solve your problem